# How do I pass my Python script into Slurm sbatch?

Tags: python, shell, slurm, sbatch

I have written I python script that I am meant to pass onto my University's Slurm sbatch system for computing. I have written a short shell script that is supposed to just enter the python script into the sbatch system, but I get an error that says:

python: can't open file 'retrieve.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I'm not sure what to do about this even after reading a lot about the system online. The python script and shell script is located in the same folder, and my shell script just says the following for now:

```
#!/bin/bash

python retrieve.py
```

I intend to add more of the necessary information to the script file once I know it works, so I was just hoping for some help with solving this problem for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you are not in the wrong directory. Without additional options, the Slurm jobs uses the directory from where you submitted the job as the working directory. So if you submitted from another folder that might be a problem.

To start to debug this, you could put in an `ls` into your jobscript (before the python call) or do an `echo $PWD` to make sure you are in the correct directory.

Or even get the workdir of your job with `sacct -j <JOBID> -o workdir` (add -p if the path is too long and gets cut).

Comment: Also make sure you are running your code from a share filesystem available on all compute nodes (which should be the case for any 'home' filesystem, but might not be the case for a 'scratch' filesystem)